# Rails 4.0 RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, testunit

When I run controller (or functional) tests, Rails 4.0 fails to auto-instantiate a controller instance (@controller) even though the same tests ran fine in Rails 3.2.
Any suggestions about how to begin solving this issue?

Sample output:

```
 $ ruby -Ilib:test test/controllers/account_controller_test.rb
[Coveralls] Set up the SimpleCov formatter.
[Coveralls] Using SimpleCov's 'rails' settings.
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby21, which recognizes
warning: 2.1.5-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.1.3.

...

  1) Error:
AccountControllerTest#test_activate_api_key:
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_filter' for AccountController:Class
    app/controllers/account_controller.rb:47:in `<class:AccountController>'
    app/controllers/account_controller.rb:46:in `<top (required)>'

  2) Error:
AccountControllerTest#test_add_mugshot:
RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
    test/functional_test_case.rb:26:in `post'
    test/controller_extensions.rb:533:in `assert_request'
    test/controller_extensions.rb:202:in `either_requires_either'
    test/controller_extensions.rb:137:in `post_requires_login'
    test/controllers/account_controller_test.rb:418:in `test_add_mugshot'
```

Account Controller definition:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

Comment: how is defined `AccountController`?

Comment: AccountController is defined in: https://github.com/JoeCohen/mushroom-observer/blob/ror4-joe/app/controllers/account_controller.rb

Comment: where is it defined in?

Comment: app / controllers / account_controller.rb

Comment: I see, but I don't see the difinition here in the post.

Comment: Based on the name of the test file (account_controller_test.rb), Rails 3 deduces the name (and location) of the controller and instantiates the controller defined in app / controllers / account_controller.rb.  I thought that Rails 4.0 is supposed to do that also.

Comment: I meant show your `app/controllers/account_controller.rb:` around 47th line

Comment: Do you mean line 97?  (Lines 1-96 are comments.)
 43 #
 44 ################################################################################
 45 
 46 class AccountController < ApplicationController
 47   before_filter :login_required, :except => [
 48     :email_new_password,
...

Comment: please update your post with the code

Comment: added Account Controller and Application Controller class definition lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `ApplicationController` isn't derived from `ActionController::Base` when it was used during definition of the `AccountController`, so add `require` before `AccountController` declaration:

```
# file app/controllers/account_controller.rb
require 'app/controllers/application_controller'

class AccountController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required, :except => [
```

Comment: Thank you Малъ Скрылевъ! Adding a require solved the problem.  The problem appears to come from files loading in a different order in Rails 4.  The application's test_helper file attempted to re-open the definition of ApplicationController.  This worked fine in Rails 3.  But it looks like Rails 4 loads test_helper before it loads the controllers.  So instead of re-opening ApplicationController, the test_helper file gave it an initial definition, which did not derive from ActionController::Base.